# Нужна помощь с кодом реализации слайд-шоу

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Как программно реализовать слайд-шоу в Visual Studio?
Какими элементами управления необходимо для этого воспользоваться, помимо PictureBox?

Comment: наверное еще `Timer`?

Comment: Что значит _слайд-шоу в Visual Studio_?

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам простейший пример - [A Simple Image Slide Show](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23082/A-Simple-Image-Slide-Show)

**Часть кода :**

```
private void showImage(string path)
{
    Image imgtemp = Image.FromFile(path);
    pictureBox1.Width = imgtemp.Width / 2;
    pictureBox1.Height = imgtemp.Height / 2;
    pictureBox1.Image = imgtemp;
}

private void nextImage()
{
    if(selected == folderFile.Length - 1)
    {
        selected = 0; 
        showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
    else
    {
        selected = selected + 1; showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    nextImage();
}
```